# Some Sobolev inequality

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I was doing some work in spectral theory and it seems to imply the following inequality: on $\mathbb{R}^d$, we have for any $m\ge 1$,

$\|D\psi\|^m_{L^2} \le \|D^m \psi\|_{L^2}\cdot\|\psi\|^{m-1}_{L^2}$

Presumably for any $\psi\in H^m(\mathbb{R}^d)$, but technically I also need some decay at infinity.

Is this inequality true ? Is it known ? Sorry if this is classical. Also note there is no constant in the upper bound.

Thanks !

Comment: This is a special case of an inequality stated in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality), just before reference.

Comment: Interesting. Indeed it implies $\|u\|_{H^1}^m\le \|u\|_{H^m}\cdot\|u\|_{L^2}^{m-1}$. This is not exactly the same as here since this upper bound seems in principle bigger, with all the partial derivatives contributing. Any reference for this wiki inequality ? I'd like to see the classical proof. And I don't really see how it follows from this Gagliardo-Nirenberg.

Comment: Ok, I found it in the original paper of Nirenberg "on elliptic partial differential equations". It is indeed a special case of the Theorem on p. 125, except there is a constant there in the upper bound. Anyway thanks for guidance, I'm glad the inequality is correct. Interesting to reprove a famous inequality using very unrelated arguments :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a more general form is true, in the case $p=2$ there is a much more elementary argument (as sketched in the wiki page linked in the comments). We will use the equality
$$ \lVert D^k\psi \rVert_{L^2(\Bbb R^d)}^2 := \sum_{|\alpha|=k} \int_{\Bbb R^d} |D^{\alpha}\psi|^2\,\,\mathrm{d}x = \int_{\Bbb R^d} |\xi|^{2k}|\hat{\psi}|^2 \,\mathrm{d} \xi,$$
which follows by the Plancherel theorem. The result is vacuous if $m=1,$ so assume that $m>1.$ Then we can use Hölder's inequality with $p = m,$  and $f(\xi) = |\xi|^2|\hat\psi|^{\frac2m},$ $g(\xi) = |\hat\psi|^{\frac{2m-2}m}$ to get
$$\begin{split} \int_{\Bbb R^n} |\xi|^2|\hat\psi|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\xi &= \int_{\Bbb R^n} f(\xi)g(\xi) \,\mathrm{d}\xi \\
&\leq \left( \int_{\Bbb R^n} f(\xi)^m \,\mathrm{d}\xi\right)^{\frac1m}\left( \int_{\Bbb R^n} g(\xi)^{\frac{m}{m-1}} \,\mathrm{d}\xi\right)^{\frac{m-1}m} \\
&= \left( \int_{\Bbb R^n} |\xi|^{2m} |\hat\psi|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\xi\right)^{\frac1m}\left( \int_{\Bbb R^n} |\hat\psi|^2 \,\mathrm{d}\xi\right)^{\frac{m-1}m}, 
\end{split}$$
so the result follows by combining these results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. There is just a typo, $g(\xi) = |\hat{\psi}|^{\frac{2m-2}{m}}$ instead.

Comment: @Lonewolf Indeed thanks, I've corrected my answer.